# HTTP header authentication not working with gradle publish

Tags: github, gradle, oauth, publish

**The following documentation describes how to use HTTP header authentication:**
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:authentication_schemes

**I did as described, answer: Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized**

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "my-url-does-not-matter-now"
            
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
                name = "Authorization"
                value = "token my-token"
            }
            authentication {
                header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Interesting enough, if i change to password protected works.**

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "my-url-does-not-matter-now"
            credentials {
                username "user"
                password "my-token"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can assume my url and token works.

Thoughts please? thanks in advance

Comment: Same here - and I was following gitlab package docs. Weird, but using username/password works just fine. Thanks for providing that!